# Checkboxes: how do I set the default values or show the user defined values using Form API?

Tags: forms

I am using an checkboxes element within a form in module that I started developing for Drupal 7. This is my first attempt at module development and using the Form API. I am creating a list of checkboxes that list down all the content types of a specific site. An array of all the content types can be obtained by using the following: `$nodeTypesRaw=node_type_get_names();`. An array with the machine names of the content types as the keys and the human readable names as the values are obtained.

By default, I would like all the checkboxes to be selected and when the form is submitted. How do I achieve that? The Form API pages on the drupal site aren't very helpful with regards to setting the default values for checkboxes.

```
$nodeTypesRaw=node_type_get_names();
$nodeMachineNames=array_keys($nodeTypesRaw);
$form['process_comments']['custommod_published_comments_select_node_types']['custommod_published_comments_node_types_checkboxes']=array(
          '#deafult_value'=>$nodeMachineNames,
          '#options'=>$nodeTypesRaw,
          '#type'=>'checkboxes',
);
```

I initially started out with the above code, but it won't work. It does display the list of checkboxes, but they are not checked by default. The variable does get on form submission though (checked via drush and var_dump).

Comment: It's `#default_value`, not `#deafult_value`. FA not AF.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [Drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/228160):

```
$form['element_id'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#options' => array(1 => "One", 2 => "Two", 3 => "Three"),
  '#default_value' => array(1, 3),
);
```

Default value is set as an array representing keys of selected options.

Looking at the code in your question, problem is with spelling. you are setting `'#deafult_value'` when you want to set `'#default_value'`.

Comment: An array of all the content types can be obtained by using the following: `$nodeTypesRaw=node_type_get_names();`. An array with the machine names of the content types as the keys and the human readable names as the values are obtained. When I set the '#default_value` using the variable `$nodeMachineNames=array_keys($nodeTypesRaw);`, the checkboxes remain un-checked.

Comment: @vr3690 Nope, you didn't set default value. See comment under your question, or update to my answer.

Answer (score 11):

You need to give an array of option *keys* (not values) as the default value, e.g.

```
$options = array(
  'option_1' => t('Option 1'),
  'option_2' => t('Option 2'),
  'option_3' => t('Option 3'),
);

$defaults = array_keys($options);

$form['checkboxes'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#title' => t('Something'),
  '#options' => $options,
  '#default_value' => $defaults,
);
```

Comment: Hi, I am already using similar code. I have edited my answer and added the same to it. This does not work.

Comment: Works fine for me in a blank install, are you sure you haven't got a typo in `#default_value` like @Mołot suggests

Comment: Just wondering, did it change at some point? Because I'm looking right now at `form_process_checkbox` and  `form_process_checkboxes` of Drupal 7 and there is no mechanism that would allow for this to work, and of course it doesn't work for me. https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/7.x/includes/form.inc#L3270-L3351

Comment: Not that I know of @ŁukaszZaroda...if you look at [`user_account_form`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_account_form/7.x) for example, the same method is used there for the roles