# Why are default values in a checkboxes $form not displayed?

Tags: forms

I'm having a drupal form (7.x) of type `checkboxes`.

I have an array of values for my checkboxes.

```
$options = array(
    'uid'         => 'UID',
    'name'        => 'Name',
    'mail'        => 'E-mail',
    'created'     => 'Created',
    'edit_node'   => 'Edit',
    'cancel_node' => 'Cancel',
);
```

I have an array of default selected values.

```
$defaults = array(
    'uid'         => 'UID',
    'name'        => 'Name',
);
```

And now I try to make the default values selected by default, like this:

```
$form['dynamic_user_fields'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#title' => t("Dynamic User Fields"),
    '#options' => $options,
    '#default_value' => $defaults,
    '#description' => t("Select the fields to display in the view."),
);
```

But this is not working, all checkboxes are unchecked by default. Where is my mistake?

---

**What is not working so far**: I've seen [this related question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/80708/13526) but the answers do not work.

What I've tried:

(1) using numeric keys does not work.

```
'#default_value' => array(1, 2),
```

[image: numeric keys]

(2) using array keys does not work.

```
'#default_value' => array('uid', 'name'),
```

[image: array keys]

(3) using array structure does not work.

```
'#default_value' => array('uid' => 'UID', 'name' => 'Name')
```

[image: array structure]

Any ideas?

---

**References**

- This is the full code I'm Using: [views_handler_filter_dynamic_fields.inc#l317](http://drupalcode.org/project/views_dynamic_fields.git/blob/26912bc:/handlers/views_handler_filter_dynamic_fields.inc#l317)
- This is a demo site: [drupal-7/dynamic-user-fields](http://alex.parliamentwatch.org/drupal-7/dynamic-user-fields)
- Related issue: [#1245838 Default fields should be checked initially](https://drupal.org/node/1245838)

I stepped up to maintain this module but the code base is a migrated D6 module.

Answer (score -1):

For form elements expecting multi-value defaults, Drupal expects an array where keys and values are equal to the keys in your options array. Something like the following should work:

```
$defaults = array(
    'uid' => 'uid',
    'name' => 'name',
);
```

You may also use `$defaults = drupal_map_assoc(array('uid', 'name'));`.